# MySQL results array into php variables?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL result set

```
$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);
```

I would like to assign all of these results PHP variables that I can use on the page.  What's the easiest way?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean get an array of results, or turn the array into individual variables? Your quoted piece of code would just tell you how many columns were returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Access via $row["name"]

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Access via $row[0] and $row["name"]

Complete example...

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row[0];echo $row["name"];  
}
```

Will print "id" and "name".

Answer (score 2):

Try [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) which return results as an array with column name as associate key

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
/* $row will be an array */
/* and the column wil be the associate key */
```

**OR**

you can use [`mysql_fetch_field`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php), which provide even more information

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching multiple rows, you will need a while loop.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['column_name'];
}
```

This will execute the code in the curly brackets for each row result. In the example, printing a field called 'column_name'.